# Python3 sums.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-idle

So I've been at this all night. Very new to programming and my objective was to use squareEach(nums) which is a list of numbers that I'd modify by squaring each entry. Next, sumList(nums) is a list of numbers, return the sum o fthe numbers in the list. Then, toNumbers(strList) strList is a list of strings, each of which represents a number. Modify each by converting it to a number. Finally use these functions to implement a program that computes the sum of the squares of numbers read from a file.

For this I'm using a file I named numbers.txt which contains...

1

2

3

Here is my program so far, I'm getting None as answer though with the numbers.txt I want to/should get 14 as an answer.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

# Caleb Webb
# 03/08/14
# A program which takes 3 functions and computes the sum of the squares of the
# numbers read from a file.

def toNumbers(strList):
    for i in range(len(strList)):
        strList[i] = int(strList[i])

def squareEach(nums):
    nums = []
    for i in nums:
        nums = nums.append(i**2)
    return nums

def sumList(x):
    return (x[0] + sumList(x[1:])) if x else 0

def main():
    file = input("Please enter a file name: ")
    fobj = open(file, "r")
    strList = fobj.readlines()
    fobj.close()
    nums = toNumbers(strList)
    x = squareEach(nums)
    result = sumList(x)
    print("The sum of the squares of the values in the file is", result)
main()
```

Comment: You are overwriting `nums` in `squareEach`. `squareNums` returns `[]` for any input.

Comment: What do you expect `strList[i] = (strList[i])` to do?

Comment: `sumList` has the `return` inside the loop and a `result` variable that was probably supposed to be `accumulator`.

Answer (score 1):

You got several problems there, already pointed out in the comments to your question. They could be fixed with something like this:

```
def toNumbers(strList):
    return [int(s) for s in strList]

def squareEach(nums):
    return [a**2 for a in nums]

def sumList(nums):
    return sum(nums)
```

Or your whole program could be written as:

```
with open(input('File name: '), 'r') as f:
    print('The square sum is ', sum(int(l)**2 for l in f))
```

---

You own `sum` with accumulator:

```
def sumList(nums):
    accumulator = 0
    for i in nums:
        accumulator += i
    return accumulator
```

(Although when I hear "accumulator" I have to think of function programming where you use accumulators in order to obtain tail-recursiveness. Which is utter non-sense in python as python shuns TCO by design.)

Comment: You don't even need to `strip` the lines. `int` is fine with leading and trailing whitespace.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I cannot use sum. The point is to get around using the default command of sum and create one of our own.

Comment: @user3404742 Then it is just a stupid homework assignment which aims completely away from reality.

Comment: @Hyperboreus: List comprehensions and built-in functions are useful, but people need to learn procedural thinking and the basics of loops and control flow somehow.

Comment: `def sumList(x): return (x[0]+sumList(x[1:])) if x else 0`.

Comment: That's exactly what it is. It's the same as telling someone they can't use a calculator on a math test because in life if they ever have to do any of this they'll have these at their disposal. I did remove return from the loop and now my answer is 0. I'm not understanding what they're meaning when they say that the result is supposed to be the accumulator. I'm kind of drawing blanks at this point, I've dug myself in one of those pits :(

Comment: @user3404742 I have added a `sumList` with accumulator.

Comment: Okay if you look at my code up top now I've edited it. I'm getting an error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/local/files/cwebb002/csc221/lab06/sums.py", line 30, in <module>
    main()
  File "/local/files/cwebb002/csc221/lab06/sums.py", line 26, in main
    nums = toNumbers(strList)
  File "/local/files/cwebb002/csc221/lab06/sums.py", line 10, in toNumbers
    strList[i] = int(strList[i])
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '["1, 2, 3"]\n'

Comment: No ideas on what it could be?

Comment: @user3404742 `'["1, 2, 3"]'` is not a list. It is a string. What does your input file look like?

Answer (score 0):

```
f=open('num.txt','r+')
numArray=[]
for line in f:
   numArray.append(int(line))
result=sum(int(i)**2 for i in numArray)
print(result)
```

num.txt

1

3

5

3

1